# Saturation Cascade MOSFETS (Need Help from EE Experts)

Tags: mosfet, saturation, cascode

this is a very straightforward question.

I'm running a Harmonic simulation on ADS where I need to design a cascode amplifier of two NMOS and one PMOS, that have a gain higher than Av > -100. The catch is that all my MOSFETs need to be in saturation mode.

All I want to know if I did my calculations to keep them all in saturation mode correctly. I design everything but I need help specifically with that part. Here's the design.
[image: MOSFET cascode schematic]

The equations:
[image: calculations]

Don't worry about looking at anything else, just the Saturation equations. If I do them correctly, then the rest of the circuit will work.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use \$M1SAT > 0\$, \$M2SAT > 0\$ and \$M3SAT < 0\$ (since that is a PMOS) to check for saturation. However, I did want to point out that your \$M2OD\$ and \$M3OD\$ will not be the overdrive voltage \$V_{GS} - V_{TH}\$.